# Can google map api be used on another kind of map(Eg: Leaflet map?)? In Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

For example, if i want to filter markers, i can use the google map API to do it. But does it still work if i use another map instead of google map to display the markers?

Answer (score 0):

No. As the [documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter#0) says, if you integrate Google Maps Flutter plugin, your app will:

> - Display a Google Map
> - Retrieve map data from a web service
> - Display this data as markers on the Map

With the Google Maps Flutter plugin, you can add maps **based on Google maps data** to your application. If you change the map, you cannot use google map api.

You can also use [the Huawei Map Flutter Plugin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050296908). It uses the WGS 84 GPS coordinate system, which meets most map development requirements.